# How to fill combobox with database values with method from DAL

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a table called Departments where the column i wish to populate my combobox with is named DeptId.  below is the datatable i created in my DAL class, but i cant for my life figure out how to put these values into deptCombobox in my form1 class.  I am trying to attach it to a button named refreshButton_Click, but nothing works no matter what i try

```
          //DAL

 public DataTable fillDeptCombo()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=");

        con.Open();
        string queryText = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, con);


        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;

        }

       //controller
    public DataTable fillDeptCombo()
    {
        return dal.fillDeptCombo();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is it for windows forms or web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned "form1", I assume it is for windows forms.
In your form1 cs code, this should do it.

```
DAL dl=new DAL()
Datatable dt=DAL.fillDeptCombo()
combobox.datasource=dt;
combobox.valuemember="deptID" //replace this with your value
combobox.displayMember="DeptName" //replace this with your text
```

Comment: Thank you! with a bit of tinkering i made this code that works

DAL dal=new DAL();
                DataTable dt= dal.fillDeptCombo();
                for (int i= 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DepartmentCombobox.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["DeptId"]);
                }